# Manipulating an Azure table through OData

Tags: azure, odata

If I have an Azure table, what (if anything) do I need to do to expose it through OData?

Also, what does the OData URL look like? If my Table Url is mytable.table.core.windows.net, where should I point my Visual Studio Web reference to have access to this data?

Comment: Please check out this blog post by Jon Udell: http://blog.jonudell.net/2010/02/09/producing-and-consuming-odata-feeds-an-end-to-end-example/. HTH

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by:

> expose it through OData

The only way to access data in an Azure table is via the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179421.aspx) which is all OData.  So as long has you have the correct authentication details (which might be non standard, I haven't tried to use it this way), all of your tables are already exposed as OData. (the url should be `http://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable`)

If you're looking to use Azure tables in a Visual Studio project, rather than accessing it via the API, generally it's easier to just use [the storage client library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.aspx).

If you want to expose the data in a table using some form or authentication other than what is currently provided (maybe you want to make it available publicly without giving away your storage keys) you will have to create your own wrapper service to do this (similar to the method that is mentioned in the link provided by Gaurav)